# WPF ContextMenu bind MenuItem Icon to MenuItem Header

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

Please explain why this dosn't work..

```xml
 <ContextMenu>     
      <MenuItem>
          <MenuItem.Header>
               <TextBox Name="tbColor" Text="Black" />
          </MenuItem.Header>
          <MenuItem.Icon>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=tbColor,Path=Text}" />
          </MenuItem.Icon>                                                                    
      </MenuItem>
 </ContextMenu>
```

I have tried several ways but nothing. `RelativeSource` doesn't work..

Edit.. binding from another control works..

```
<DataGrid Foreground="{Binding ElementName=tbColor,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource textToBrushConverter}}">          
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>....
```

Comment: Why do you think you can add a `TextBox` to a property that expects an `Image`?

Comment: I dosn't expect an image. You can place whatever control you want there. In the original code there will be a Rectangle changing color based on what you enter in header textbox, using a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the original code working like this.. ugly but for my own sanity..

```
<MenuItem.Header>
   <TextBox Name="tbColor" Text="Black" TextChanged="tbColor_TextChanged" />
</MenuItem.Header>
<MenuItem.Icon>
   <Rectangle Name="rectangleColor" Width="20" Height="20" />
</MenuItem.Icon>
```

And in code behind..

```
private void tbColor_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            rectangleColor.Fill = new SolidColorBrush((Color) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(((TextBox) sender).Text));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick look through [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CONTROLS.HEADEREDITEMSCONTROL.HEADER%29;k%28VS.XAMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true) about `ContextMenu`, `MenuItem`, and `HeaderedItemsControl` makes it look like you can put anything you want in a `MenuItem` `Header`.  Closer inspection reveals that this is not the case.  The `Header` property of a `MenuItem` is actually looking for a string.  You can get by with placing a `TextBlock` inside the `Header`, but not a `TextBox`.

Though I haven't looked into it in depth, I suspect that the same(except with Image) is true of the `Icon` property of the `MenuItem` object.

Comment: I can explicitly set any control i want in header. I can also bind to the texbox from a control outside the contextMenu.

Answer (score 0):

Context menu outside the visual tree of your control so can't find element name.
Try -

> {Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"

Comment: Tried this before in different variations but i didn't work. Also shouldn't you be able to bind within the same control.